# Save an inline rotated image in docx xml

Tags: xml, ms-word, ms-office, openxml, docx

I'm trying to figure out how to save an inline rotated image in XML for MS Word properly. If I only specify the `wp:extent` and the `a:xfrm rot` properties which are responsible for the size and the rotation of the image, the image itself gets cropped at its edges when opened in MS Word:

[image: MS Word screenshot]

An XML file obtained from an MS Word document with a rotated image in addition to `wp:extent` also has a `wp:effectExtent` property with non-zero values `l`, `t`, `r`, `b`. The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.wordprocessing.effectextent?view=openxml-2.8.1) says *this element specifies the additional extent which shall be added to each edge of the image (top, bottom, left, right) in order to compensate for any drawing effects applied to the DrawingML object*. Once this property is removed, the image gets cropped. However, I cannot figure out how exactly this property is related to image rotation. My first thought was that these values are summands which should be applied to the image size in order to get its bounding box. Yet, this doesn't seem to be true as they do not allow to calculate a bounding box for some angles.

Does anyone know how to get proper values of `effectExtent` in order to save a rotated image properly?